# Laravel inserts three database results instead of one

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to insert two different values to postgres database by using one eloquent query. The problem I'm facing is that Laravel somehow inserts three same values (in this case - sends 3 notifications to channel and 1 to user). I want to send one notification for the channel and one notification for the user.

Could this be problem, should I divide this query to two different eloquent queries, or the problem is not here?

```
 Notification::insert([[
   //Send notification to channel (for this, laravel inserts three notifications)
   'user' => $owner,
   'channel' => $channel_id,
   'type' => 6,
   'param_1' => $customer_id,
   'param_2' => $tier_id,
   'created_at' => $notification_date,
 ], [
    //Send notification to user
    'user' => $customer_id,
    'channel' => $channel_id,
    'type' => 4,
    'param_1' => $tier_id,
    'param_2' => 0,
    'created_at' => $notification_date,
 ]]);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there isn't a problem with your code, but in my opinion, this is a bad practice in Laravel, I don't know the type of error that you're getting, but try to avoid the hard-coding my friend, I don't know where you getting from the variables, but if I was in your place, and if this notification gonna triggered every time after an event I'm gonna work with Laravel Observers.

If you are listening for many events on a given model, you may use observers to group all of your listeners into a single class. Observer classes have method names which reflect the Eloquent events you wish to listen for. Each of these methods receives the affected model as their only argument. The `make:observer` Artisan command is the easiest way to create a new observer class:

```
php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers